# CSS Chrome : Cannot hide scrollbar automatically

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

See this code :

```
html{position:relative;min-height:100%;}
```

and

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="main" style="width:200px;max-height:100px;">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

In addition, `Textarea` scrollbar and resize grabber cannot hiding too.

How can I fix it using CSS?

in Chrome(MacOS). But Safari works well.

This code is example for quick understanding.

The contents are large enough to require scrollbar.

**UPDATE** : https://jsfiddle.net/xu3q4m4w/9/

I guess This problem is relates to [LINK](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/displaying-scroll-bar).

Comment: why don't you set `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: I think it better if you use the `max-width + width` with large content  to make it responsive as I mentioned in my answer. Never use width:1500px in this case

Comment: My problem is `auto hide` not working.

Comment: pls explain me how `auto hide` do you expect? :D

Comment: I think `scrollbar` shown by hover event before. not always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out this problem. It Happen by only old chrome version (48.0.2564.97)

Now fix it. (48.0.2564.103 )

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2):

`height` set into `100%` create scroll bar. Try to fix into `max-height:100%`.
 as well as `width`. you should set into `width:100%` or `max-width:100%` to get full width, not in pixel.

**UPDATED:**

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;">
    <div id="main" style="max-width:1500px;height:200px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xu3q4m4w/3/)

Answer (score 0):

use this fiddle overflow-x:hidden

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;">
    <div id="main" style="width:1500px;height:200px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/xu3q4m4w/1/)

Comment: content should be shown. `overflow-x:hidden` is incorrect way.